# displaying an image cropping dialog in an apps script Gui

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an apps-script which inserts a structural diagram for chemical into a gdocs Document based on some details pulled from a spreadsheet, however often the image is often not well centred like so;

---

[image]

---

> penicillin image courtesy of DrugBank.ca
>   (http://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB01053)

hence I would like to give the user one last chance to crop the image before inserting.

There is a tool called [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_API.html) which works with jQuery, but I presume its falling foul of the caja compiler when I try to run it. (I get "Node not editable; no action performed.") as the library loads.

Do I have any options to stay within the apps-script gui?

obviously I can split the front-end off to some other non-caja-sandbox, and just send the actions to be handled by apps-script, but thats gonna require me having some app setup, whereas the apps-script is nice and contained.

Answer (score 0):

In the short term, if it doesn't pass Caja there's little we can do. In the medium term we are attempting to dramatically improve what will pass Caja, and hopefully the situation will improve.

If you can find a crop implementation written in "pure" jQuery itself - that is, sample code and not a plugin - you will probably be able to use it.